# C++ polymorphism in simple example

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I have this set of classes.

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(uint32_t attr1, uint32_t attr2);

    virtual uint32_t get_attr1() const;
    virtual uint32_t get_attr2() const;

private:
    uint32_t attr1;
    uint32_t attr2;
};

class Dog: public Animal {
public:
    Dog(uint32_t attr1, uint32_t attr2, uint32_t attr3);
    uint32_t get_attr3() const;

private:
    uint32_t attr3;
};

class Cat: public Animal {
public:
    Cat(uint32_t attr1, uint32_t attr2, uint32_t attr4);
    uint32_t get_attr4() const;

private:
    uint32_t attr4;
};
```

Now I want to have

```
vector<Animal*> animals;
```

and few functions that are declared as follows:

```
void f(Dog* dog);
void f(Cat* cat);
```

and this code:

```
for (auto animal: animals) {
    f(animal);
}
```

how to make polymorphism out of this code? It looks like animal is not treated like cat or dog.

Comment: Why are you dealing with a pointer to a vector? Also, the `f` functions should be members of the `cat` and `dog` classes.

Comment: I dont want the f function to be member of classes due to design choice. Agree with the pointer though

Comment: If you're set doing it like this, then look into [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: You need to make `f()` a virtual member of `Animal` and put the separate implementations in the respective `Cat` and `Dog` class if you want this variety of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an `f()` overload that takes an `Animal*` as input, then your `for` loop will work as you have written it.  To then call separate `f()` overloads for `Dog` and `Cat`, you will have to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) at runtime, eg:

```
void f(Dog* dog)
{
    // do something only a dog can do ...
}

void f(Cat* cat)
{
    // do something only a cat can do ...
}

void f(Animal *animal)
{
    if (Dog *dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal)) {
        f(dog);
    }
    else if (Cat *cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal)) {
        f(cat);
    }
}

...

for (auto animal: animals) {
    f(animal);
}
```

However, this goes against the principles of polymorphism.  If `f()` needs to do different things depending on the type of `Animal` it is called on, it should be a virtual method of the `Animal` class, and then descendants can override it as needed:

```
class Animal {
public:
    ...
    virtual ~Animal() {} // <-- don't forget this!
    ...
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Dog: public Animal {
public:
    ...
    void f() override;
};

class Cat: public Animal {
public:
    ...
    void f() override;
};

void Dog::f()
{
    // do something only a dog can do ...
}

void Cat::f()
{
    // do something only a cat can do ...
}

...

for (auto animal: animals) {
    animal->f();
}
```

Comment: And there is [visitor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/4579/visitor-pattern/15127/visitor-pattern-example-in-c#t=201708110127395809679) to avoid to add too many virtual methods.